# Check whether variable is defined using nikic/php-parser

Tags: php, static-analysis, php-parser

I'm trying to build a static code analysis tool and I would like to check if the variables in a file are defined. Currently I'm using nikic/PHP-Parser (https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser), but I'm not sure if what I'm attempting is even possible.

So my question is: is it possible to check whether is (possibly) set. So does the variable contain a different value than null? Since the code is not executed in static analysis I feel like it might be impossible to "guess" whether the variable might be null, before giving it to a function for example.

An example:

```
$page = Expertise::find(get_the_ID());
$relatedNews = $page->connectedNews->take(-3)->reverse();
```

The second line might give us an exception in this case, when `$page` turned out to be null. I would like to detect these kinds of instabilities in the code using static analysis.

Here's a piece of code of what I'm attempting using PHP-Parser.

```
class NodeVisitor extends NodeVisitorAbstract
{
    public function enterNode(Node $node)
    {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Expr\Variable) {
            // is not null (is set)
            // or if that's not possible: is defined before reference?
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: to be more clear on why I'm doing this, I'm trying to build an application that detects possible 500 errors without knowing anything about the execution of the code.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to check if they're defined before they're referenced?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and a sample piece of code to show what you want to check for.

Comment: You should be able to check whether there's any assignment expression where the variable is the target.

Comment: IDEs like PhpStorm warn about using variables that aren't defined, so it's certainly possible to do this in static analysis. Whether it's possible for *you* depends on your programming skill.

Comment: I added some more information to my question. Hopefully this clears up my question.

Comment: If you're writing this app as a programming exercise, you could check out [PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/), which uses `nikic/php-parser` and provides the described functionality. If you're writing this app because you didn't know PHPStan existed, you could just use PHPStan. :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky Well yes and no. I would definitely also want to know how to check this, but my main question is whether I can check if the variable is set. So does it contain a different value than `null`? Since the code is not executed in static analysis I feel like it might be impossible to "guess" whether the variable might be null, before giving it to a function for example.

Comment: @NigelRen I added some code. Hopefully this gives you more information on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: In the example code, you would need to know if `Expertise::find(get_the_ID())` could return null.  If you didn't know anything about the source for all of the code, every access of a variable could potentially lead to an error.

Comment: @NigelRen Ah yes exactly :-) For your information, I do know about the source of all code, so I could check whether Expertise::find could return null I guess.